# Find Website Address in String and Convert to URL Link

Tags: ios, swift, string, web

I have a String which may display a website address.  I would like to display the website address as a link.  How would I go about doing this?
Example

```
label.text = "Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.  The website is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"

let input = label.text
    let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
    let matches = detector.matches(in: input!, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (input?.utf16.count)!))

    for match in matches {
        guard let range = Range(match.range, in: input!) else { continue }
        let url = input![range]

        print(url)
    }
```

I can print https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask however, I am not sure how I can turn this into a link whilst keeping my other text inside the string.

Comment: Change your UILabel to UITextView and add this lines `textview.isEditable = false
textview.dataDetectorTypes = .all`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was pretty simple.

I changed my UILabel to UITextView. This then picks up all emails, URLS etc.

In Attribute Inspector
I added (clicked) phone numbers, links, address in Data Detectors.
Then de-selected editable and kept selectable activated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSAttributedString for this

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: ".  The website is")
attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask", range: NSRange(location: 19, length: 55))
```

textView.attributedText = attributedString

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {

     UIApplication.shared.open(URL, options: [:])
     return false
 }
```